# How do I escape tilde character in scala?

Tags: scala

Given that i have a file that  looks like this

```
CS~84~Jimmys Bistro~Jimmys
...
```

using tilde (~) as a delimiter, how can i split it?

```
val company = dataset.map(k=>k.split(""\~"")).map(
k => Company(k(0).trim, k(1).toInt, k(2).trim, k(3).trim)
```

The above don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I don't see where it needs to be escaped.

```
scala> val str = """CS~84~Jimmys Bistro~Jimmys"""
str: String = CS~84~Jimmys Bistro~Jimmys

scala> str.split('~')
res15: Array[String] = Array(CS, 84, Jimmys Bistro, Jimmys)
```

And the array elements don't need to be trimmed unless you know that errant spaces can be part of the input.

Comment: Agreed. Although a char version with `~` is a bit special, as in this overload the input is not regex. Still, even with normal quotes "~" is works as expected.

Comment: ... and if you trim, add an additional step instead of repeating: `str.split('~').map(_.trim)`

Comment: Thanks jwvh and Suma, that worked. Suma thanks for the tip about trim.